# How to decrypt AES-128-CBC encrypted ts file with CryptoJS?

Tags: javascript, aes, cryptojs, m3u8

I got a m3u8 file which looks like this.

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="1.key",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000000
#EXTINF:2.000000,
1.ts
```

I know how to decrypt the ts file with openssl.

```
openssl enc -d -aes-128-cbc -iv 00000000000000000000000000000000 -K bf2984079bdbbf2834ba60319bb6a717 -in 1.ts -out out.ts
```

But how to decrypt the ts file with CryptoJS. (https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js)
Can someone tell me how to do that?